# .Net authorization/authentication idea

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

My applications is ASP.Net MVC and has a lot of views. I want to give every user different permissions. For example, user1 can see view1 and view2, user2 can see view2 and view3, etc.

I was thinking to do this: In a table in a database to store a row for each user and names of the views he is allowed to see. Then, before each ActionResult method in the controller I'll write:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "NameOfView")]
```

Is there a way this could work?

Comment: Yes, this can work. What have you tried? Specifically, you should be looking at the `ActionFilterAttribute` if such functionality does not already exist (IIRC, it does).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to extend the AuthorizeAttribute.

Answer (score 0):

Of course.If you used the default Asp.Net Mvc template,then it would work.